# Camel enrich SQL syntax issue

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

I'm tasked with creating a Camel route using Camel version 2.20.0 that takes a line in from a CSV file uses a value from that line in the SQL statement where clause and merges the results and outputs them again.  If I hardcode the identifier in the SQL statement it works fine, if I try and use a dynamic URI I get an error.

The route is:

```
from("file:///tmp?fileName=test.csv")
.split()
.tokenize("\n")
.streaming()
.parallelProcessing(true)
.setHeader("userID", constant("1001"))
//.enrich("sql:select emplid,name from employees where emplid = '1001'",
.enrich("sql:select name from employees where emplid = :#userID",
     new AggregationStrategy() {
        public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange,
                                     Exchange newExchange)    {...
```

As I said if I uncomment the line with the hardcoded 1001 it queries the db and works as expected.  However using the ':#userID' syntax I get an Oracle error of:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    Message History
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
    [route3            ] [route3            ] [file:///tmp?fileName=test.csv                                                 ] [        43]
    [route3            ] [log5              ] [log                                                                           ] [         2]
    [route3            ] [setHeader2        ] [setHeader[userID]                                                             ] [         0]
    [route3            ] [enrich2           ] [enrich[constant{sql:select name from employees where emplid = :#userID] [        40]
```

The table is clearly there because it works when the value is hardcoded so it's got something to do with passing in the dynamic value.  I've tried lots of variations on how to pass that variable in, inside single quotes, using values from the body instead of headers, etc. and haven't found the working combination yet though I've seen lots of similar seemingly working examples.

I've turned trace on it appears the header is correctly set as well:

```
o.a.camel.processor.interceptor.Tracer   :  >>> (route3) setHeader[userID, 1001] --> enrich[constant{sql:select name from employees where emplid = :#userID}] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileAbsolutePath=/tmp/test.csv, CamelFileLastModified=1513116018000, CamelFileLength=26, CamelFileName=test.csv, CamelFileNameConsumed=test.csv, CamelFileNameOnly=test.csv, CamelFileParent=/tmp, CamelFilePath=/tmp/test.csv, CamelFileRelativePath=test.csv, userID=1001}, BodyType:String, Body:1001,SomeValue,MoreValues
```

What needs to change to make this work?

I should also note I've tried this approach, using various syntax options to refer to the header value,  without any luck:

```
.enrich().simple("sql:select * from employees where emplid = :#${in.header.userID}").aggregate ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html):

> From **Camel 2.16** **onwards** both **enrich** and **pollEnrich** supports dynamic endpoints that uses an Expression to compute the uri, which allows to use data from the current Exchange. In other words all what is told above no longer apply and it just works.

As you are using 2.20, I think you may try this example:

```
from("file:///tmp?fileName=test.csv")
.split()
.tokenize("\n")
.streaming()
.parallelProcessing(true)
.setHeader("userID", constant("1001"))
//.enrich("sql:select emplid,name from employees where emplid = '1001'",
.enrich("sql:select name from employees where emplid = ':#${in.header.userID}'",
    new AggregationStrategy() {
        public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange,
                                    Exchange newExchange)    {...
```

Take a look at the [Expression](http://camel.apache.org/expression.html) topic in docs for further examples.

To sum up, the expression could be:

`"sql:select name from employees where emplid = ':#${in.header.userID}'"`

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I've missed the `:#` [suffix](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html). You could see a [unit test working here](https://github.com/ricardozanini/camel-labs/blob/master/src/test/java/com/stackoverflow/camel/labs/PollEnrichDynamicEndpointRouterTest.java).

Just take care with the columns types. If it's a integer, you shouldn't need the quotes.

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately when I try that I get another exception:     `org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [99999]; error code [17034]; Non supported SQL92 token at position: 45; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 45`  which is the '{'.  It's almost like the substitutions aren't happening.

Comment: I've tried it both with and without the colon and get the same error, without the colon it throws the error at position 44.

Comment: Here's the error without the token: `org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [99999]; error code [17034]; Non supported SQL92 token at position: 44; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 44`  the message history ends with `[route3            ] [enrich2           ] [enrich[constant{sql:select name from employees where emplid = ${in.header.use] [        56]`

Comment: I've missed the quotes. Try this one: `"sql:select name from employees where emplid = '${in.header.userID}'"`. But it's strange.. seems that the dynamic expressions isn't working and this was implemented in 2.16 version.. :(

Comment: Also, trying adding your constant as integer: `.setHeader("userID", constant(1001))`. Your column is an integer or varchar?

Comment: Just edited my question, I've forgotten the `:#` suffix.

Comment: Fantastic @Ricardo!  Using your unit test I was able to narrow in on the problem.  Your unit test works of course.  When I change out Derby for Oracle it also works.  However, it fails with the same error I reported if I preface the table name with the schema (camel.projects vs projects in the sql statement) and use Oracle.  It works fine in Derby with the schema prefacing the table name.  I'm not sure where the problem lies with the schema name and Oracle but I can workaround that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the Camel docs:

> pollEnrich or enrich does **not** access any data from the current
>   Exchange which means when polling it cannot use any of the existing
>   headers you may have set on the Exchange.

The recommended way of achieving what you want is to instead use the `recipientList`, so I suggest you read up on that.

- [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html)
- [Recipient List](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html)

**Edit:**

As Ricardo Zanini rightly pointed out in his answer it is actually possible to achieve this with Camel-versions from 2.16 onwards. As the OP is using 2.20 my answer is invalid.

I will, however, keep my answer but want to point out that this is only valid if you're using an older version than 2.16.